# Prove that if $f(d) = g(d)$ for every $d\in D$ then $f=g$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

Where $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions and $D$ is a $\textit{dense}$ set.

I can only use the definition of a continuous function and definition of density (since that is all I learned) But I can seem to connect the two here, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: HINT: Show that the continuous function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ must be constant.

Comment: please repeat your question in the body of the question, and explain what you know and what you've tried so far. can you state which definitions of "continuous" and "dense" you're using?